# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You've graduated, and with graduation, as announced earlier, you get Community Promotion Ads to run on your site!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful law and court references
- interesting law-related blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/483).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately Law does not have a twitter account. [Here's an example of one, though](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/704/community-promotion-ads-2016/705#705).

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. We actually did start working on a new default ad but I can't seem to find what happened to it.

Comment: @GraceNote Not sure if it's a bug, but the auto thing isn't popping up (if that was [by-design]). Also, submitting an Area 51 ad yields me a bug. Are we supposed to get the Area 51 images up onto imgur somehow? How can we do this (I'm trying to submit an Area 51 ad here).

Comment: You can just copy the image and re-upload it through our normal image upload service, it'll end up on imgur that way. I'll look into the auto-template not being setup though.

Comment: @GraceNote Hmm... But it wouldn't necessarily be updated, will it then? Or will imgur retrieve the image from the A51 server when serving the community ad?

Comment: It will not dynamically update, no.

Answer (score 7):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: This will change if there are no questions with bounties; the size is *not* a problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow and Support Urban Planning!]

Comment: Like Martin's ad, size isn't an issue. Environmental law and regulations are actually big to planning, so it's highly relevant to this site :)

Comment: I suggest improving the contrast of the text against the background.

Comment: @Dawn Sure. Any ideas for colour? (also, if you'd like to edit the image yourself, you can.  I'm not with my computer for a couple weeks, and I don't have te ability to update it just yet :/)

Comment: There is some advice here: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/text-over-images/ several options for increasing the contrast

Answer (score 0):

[image: Discuss the workings and policies of this site]

Comment: It's not likely to win awards for graphic design, but this is only a placeholder ad until there's a site design in place.  This is "high DPI" resolution.

Comment: I don't know about this one. For me, the colour scheme is kind of hurting my eyes, and the "for" isn't really clear either. Also, is "Talking about the laws for talking about the laws" supposed to mean anything?

Comment: It's supposed to be some catchy description for meta to draw folks' interest.  Law Meta is one of the "most meta" in the SE network because the main site is about a form of [rather formal] community norms.  I heavily debated what noun to use there and am still not sure I picked the best one; decisions and discussion outcomes on Meta aren't exactly like "law" for this site, though some see them that way.  All of the colors come from colors found on this site under its current design, but I'm open to suggestions for changing them.

Comment: I'm also open to changes in the verb, which I also debated. Colors in the middle section match the title bar upper right on the main site (text and background) and the "for" has the same color as the site nav links on the right side of the main-site title bar.  The top section inverts the middle; going in that order smooths the transition from top to bottom.  The bottom section has the same colors as the title bar in the upper left of Meta pages.

Comment: I added an alternative ad on this question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Participate in Community Discussions. Visit Meta!]

Comment: In case you folks want a brighter image, this is an alternative that I've made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5s0d.jpg

Comment: This doesn't give anybody any idea of what Meta is about or *why* they would want to participate here.

Comment: @WBT I'm pretty sure that the intended audience that we want coming to meta are users who are established, and already know what meta is. It's not aimed for new users entirely - they can't even post on meta, and arguably, wouldn't even be able to vote or comment in many cases. I think it's more of a friendly reminder for users to come up and participate on meta, if anything.

Comment: It still doesn't give even established users any incentive, even the small incentive of feeling like they could accomplish something they want to accomplish, or have input into the shape and direction of the community they're part of.